# Jupyter Notebook No module named 'Grid' when Importing from Subdirectory

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, importerror

Before reading my question I would like to clarify that running the program within the python shell will run without any issues. I need to run some code through jupyter notebook and only then does importing within jupyter notebook will result in a No Module found error. This issue is described further below.

I have a project with the following hierarchy:

```
-ProjectFolder
    -test.ipynb
    -modules
        -Game.py
        -Grid.py
```

I was able to successfully import both Game.py and Grid.py into my jupyter notebook test file by adding the two lines to import each python file like below:

**test.ipynb**

```py
from modules import Game
from modules import Grid
```

Unfortunately for this project there is a hard requirement. I must import the Grid Class within the Game.py file. Because both Game.py and Grid.py reside in the same folder I thought I could simply add the line `import Grid` at the top of Game.py without any issues. I did this by adding the line  importGrid:

**Game.py**

```py
import Grid

...
class Grid(object):
    // grid structure logic
```

With that line, my test.ipynb now imports only the Game class from Game.py like so:

**test.ipynb**

```py
from modules import Game
...
class Game(object):
    // game logic
```

When running test in jupyter I unfortunately get the error `No module named 'Grid'`. Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong in this case? I have tried several things like relative imports trying `from .Grid import Grid` but this didnt work either and had a module not found error as well"